# How to get last record data with macro in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Today, I would like to share a conflict about my kind of "version control tool" project in an Excel file.
At the first, I have just three sheets in this file and you can see their functions step by step below:

1. Input Form Sheet: It gets input from a user and the user can submit all inputs to the second page with just a button. The inputs are "Software Name", "New Version Number", "Employee Name", "Description" and "Date"
2. All Records Sheet: On the second page, user can see all records of the tool which are copied from the first page.
3. Overview Sheet: This page doesn't work yet. My question is about this one. However, There are just three rows and five columns on this page. Columns are; Software Name, Last Version Number, Employee Name, Description, and Date. The rows are already written which are the Software Names; "Software_one", "Software_two", "Software_three"

> Overview sheet needs to have a button that helps to view "last record" of each software_name for the user when it is clicked.

I would like to implement a VBA code into this button to make this process happen.
I couldn't find any source about this situation on the web.

> When this button is clicked, the user should be able to view the last version number, date, description, and employee name on its own row with the last recordings.

**In order to give an example, "all records page" has three records from "Software_1" let's say. Naturally, the last row is the last record and this record should be copied to the last record page on the Software_1's row with the button and thanks to macro**

*Any comment, suggestion, or answer can help me a lot. Please provide your feedback. Thank you very much in advance. Have a nice day!*

Answer (score 0):

In order to go to the "last" cell of an Excel sheet, you can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+End</kbd>. In VBA it looks like:

```
Range(<whatever>).SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
```

There you are located on the bottom most right cell in your sheet. From there you can go to the beginning of your row and move around (or use the `.EntireRow` property).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I had an idea how to find the last cell but, I have no idea how can I do with a filtered condition. Because there will be three different software names in a cell that has "all records". For this all records page, I need to implement a VBA code which can find the last record of Software_1, Software_2 and Software_3 seperately.

Comment: I just tested: the mentioned "Ctrl+End" shortcut also works when data are filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to find the last used row.

```
Sub FindingLastRow()
'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
  LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Using SpecialCells Function
  LastRow = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

Here are some ways to find the last used column.

```
Sub FindingLastColumn()

'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last column number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(7, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastColumn = sht.UsedRange.Columns(sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

'Using Table Range
  LastColumn = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastColumn = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Columns.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Right (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastColumn = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

End Sub
```

Reference:

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba